# jQuery - transform selected <option> into simple text

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list of options (`<select>`) for user to choose. I need to make a jQuery solution that will transform the selected option into a simple text.

Example. The list:

```
<select>
<option>Oranges</option>
<option>Apples</option>
<option>Bananas</option>
</select>
```

User selected "Apples". After user clicks a special button on the page, jQuery replaces the whole list with a static text:

```
Apples
```

So, how to grab the selected option's value and replace the whole `<select>` list with it?

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ftjc1c7w/2/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**replaceWith()**](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(':selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Oranges</option>
  <option>Apples</option>
  <option>Bananas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/L9052n7w/)

```
<div id="yo">
  <select>
    <option>Oranges</option>
    <option>Apples</option>
    <option>Bananas</option>
  </select>   
</div>

$(function(){

    $div = $('#yo')

    $div.find('select').change(function(){

        $div.html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceWith`

```
$(function() {
    $(".selectField").on("change", function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xjq8thv/)